# How to Access Google Analytics Dashboard into our C# web application or portal?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am accessing Google analytics dashboard in C# Web Application but it shows that "google restricts your request". Then I create new project from google API's and enable it, now I have client id and API key.
How I will complete this task ??

I follow all instructions given on stack overflow but i not solved my problem yet.

I am accessing google analytics dashboard through i frame tag.
as like:

```
<div class="tabbable header-tabs"> <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> <li id="GoogleAnalytics" runat="server" style="display:block" ><a href="#" onclick="OpenTab('/Dashboard/GoogleAnalytics.aspx','/Dashboard/GoogleAnalytics.aspx')" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span class="hidden-inline-mobile">Google Dashboard</span> <span class="badge badge-blue font-11"></span></a> </li> </ul> <div> <div id="divForDashboard"> </div>
```

and GoogleAnalytics.aspx page has link:

```
<div> <iframe id="GoogleFrame" runat="server" src="https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/?authuser=4#/report-home/a131004071w190471815p186658623" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google analytics dashboard is a web application you cant access it programitcly.  You can access the data behind the reports that are created and then create your own reports.

[Google analytics sample](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples) as well as [authentication sample](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20Reporting%20API/v4)

```
  DateRange dateRange = new DateRange() { StartDate = "2015-06-15", EndDate = "2015-06-30" };

    // Create the Metrics object.
    Metric sessions = new Metric { Expression = "ga:sessions", Alias = "Sessions" };

    //Create the Dimensions object.
    Dimension browser = new Dimension { Name = "ga:browser" };

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest
    {
        ViewId = "XXXX",
        DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { dateRange },
        Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { browser },
        Metrics = new List<Metric>() { sessions }
    };

    List<ReportRequest> requests = new List<ReportRequest>();
    requests.Add(reportRequest);

    // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
    GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest() { ReportRequests = requests };

    // Call the batchGet method.
    GetReportsResponse response = analyticsreporting.Reports.BatchGet(getReport).Execute();
```

You are going to have to build up the same request as is in the report you are looking at in the website.  You are also going to have to design the graphical display yourself as i mentioned this will only return the data.

Comment: This means we cannot access whole dashboard as it is in our web application ??

Comment: No you can only access the data via the API what you do with the data is up to you.  Using an iframe won't work either as you need to be logged in

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo I did but i want with your help.